# Using Java Cipher in non-blocking environment

Tags: java, multithreading, security, encryption, nonblocking

We have a multi-threaded environment wherein we perform encryption and decryption using javax.crypto.Cipher class.

However, we are facing a Cipher blocking issue.

The thread dumps indicate the following state:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.security.Provider.getService(Provider.java:680)
        - locked <0x0000000481680800> (a org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:629)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:580)
          .............................................

  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.getCryptoPermission(JceSecurityManager.java:120)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000004802e0c10> (a java.lang.Class for javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2503)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.initCryptoPermission(Cipher.java:685)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:658)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:580)

java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.System.identityHashCode(Native Method)
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.hash(IdentityHashMap.java:301)
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.get(IdentityHashMap.java:334)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:173)
    - locked <0x00000004802e08b8> (a java.lang.Class for javax.crypto.JceSecurity)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:638)
```

There are many threads that are blocked at different stages of Cipher.getInstance() method waiting for other threads to perform operations so that they can release the synchronized methods/blocks. We did see that the Cipher.getInstance() method makes use of internal synchronization.

In our code, every thread makes a call to Cipher.getInstance(.....) method with a specified algorithm and provider to get the cipher object and then use it to encrypt/decrypt the data.

How can we resolve the blocking problem.

Would caching of Cipher instance be a solution to the problem. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: I fixed your title and tags; both contained [cypher] but the question is about ciphers. Cypher is a query language for graph databases such as Neo4j and has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: Why are you calling `Cipher.getInstance()` so frequently?

Comment: Using it to create a unique ID from multiple fields, then using it to be stored in DDB as primary key.

Comment: to get more context, All threads are using the same algorithm and provider. Is there a way we can pre initialize part of the cipher, so we can avoid the blocking part.